# Sql Server 2000 Puzzle

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

```
 SELECT    Id ,
           ActionDate ,
           Operation ,
           Date ,
           [Payroll Number]    
FROM 
[dbo].[tblx]

1   2018-01-10 00:00:00.000 NEW     2018-01-30 00:00:00 X0154X
2   2018-01-10 00:00:00.000 NEW     2018-01-31 00:00:00 X0154X
3   2018-01-10 00:00:00.000 NEW     2018-02-01 00:00:00 X0154X
4   2018-01-10 00:00:00.000 DELETE  2018-02-01 00:00:00 X0154X
5   2018-01-10 00:00:00.000 NEW     2018-02-02 00:00:00 X0154X
6   2018-01-10 00:00:00.000 NEW     2018-02-11 00:00:00 X0154X
```

I need the Latest record based ON Action Date for a Payroll/Date combination. So I tried this on SQL server 2000. The problem, however, is that `ROW_NUMBER()` wasn't introduced until SQL Server 2008.

This gives me 4 INSTEAD OF 5 records. Record with ID 4 is not returned as there is tie with the Action Date.

```
SELECT     Id ,
           ActionDate ,
           Operation ,
           Date ,
           [Payroll Number]
  FROM (SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM dbo.tblx AS counter
                   WHERE counter.[Payroll Number] = dbo.tblx.[Payroll Number]
                    AND counter.[Date] = dbo.tblx.[Date]
                    AND  counter.ActionDate >= dbo.tblx.ActionDate) AS rn
        FROM dbo.tblx
        WHERE Status IN ( 0, 5 )
          AND Category = 'Holiday') AS r1
  WHERE r1.rn = 1

  Id  ActionDate                Operation   Date                Payroll Number
  1   2018-01-10 00:00:00.000   NEW         2018-01-30 00:00:00 X0154X
  2   2018-01-10 00:00:00.000   NEW         2018-01-31 00:00:00 X0154X
  5   2018-01-10 00:00:00.000   NEW         2018-02-02 00:00:00 X0154X
  6   2018-01-10 00:00:00.000   NEW         2018-02-11 00:00:00 X0154X
```

Is there a way to get this without `ROW_NUMBER()` on SQL Server 2000?

Comment: You should really consider upgrading from SQL2000, that's a very old product that hasn't been supported for many years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the pre-window functions days, you could do:

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM [dbo].[tblx] x
WHERE x.ActionDate = (SELECT MAX(x2.ActionDate)
                      FROM [dbo].[tblx] x2
                      WHERE x2.[Payroll Number] = x.[Payroll Number] AND
                            x2.Date = x.Date
                     );
```

This syntax is used in databases such as MySQL, SQLite, and MS Access that do not support window functions.

If you can define "latest" by `id`, then use that instead of date in the subquery:

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM [dbo].[tblx] x
WHERE x.id = (SELECT MAX(x2.id)
              FROM [dbo].[tblx] x2
              WHERE x2.[Payroll Number] = x.[Payroll Number] AND
                    x2.Date = x.Date
             );
```

Comment: Gives me all 6 records . Problem with 2 records with same date /payroll number remains unfortunately.

--  wanted 1 ID returned FOR each row  here 

  SELECT 
         x.ActionDate ,
         x.Date ,
         x.[Payroll Number]
FROM [dbo].[tblx] x
WHERE x.ActionDate = (SELECT MAX(x2.ActionDate)
                      FROM [dbo].[tblx] x2
                      WHERE x2.[Payroll Number] = x.[Payroll Number] AND
                            x2.Date = x.Date
                     )

GROUP BY x.ActionDate ,
         x.Date ,
         x.[Payroll Number]

Comment: @JamesKhan Let me ask something: you said you want latest record, how on earth can you determine which one is last if all times are identical for these two rows?! What output do you expect? Gordon, didn't knew such approach, great to know that +1

Comment: Records with ID 1, 2,3 ,5 ,& 6. No Record with ID 4.

Comment: @James just exclude rows where `operation = DELETE`?

Answer (score 0):

This works but is not great code or sql.

```
SELECT 

             a.ActionDate ,
             a.Date ,
             a.[Payroll Number]
             , MAXC( a.id) AS ID_Required_To_Porcess

    FROM 
    [dbo].[tblx] a
    INNER JOIN ( 

    SELECT 
             x.ActionDate ,
             x.Date ,
             x.[Payroll Number]
    FROM [dbo].[tblx] x
    WHERE x.ActionDate = (SELECT MAX(x2.ActionDate)
                          FROM [dbo].[tblx] x2
                          WHERE x2.[Payroll Number] = x.[Payroll Number] AND
                                x2.Date = x.Date
                         )

    GROUP BY x.ActionDate ,
             x.Date ,
             x.[Payroll Number]


             ) b ON a.ActionDate=b.actionDate AND a.date=b.date AND a.[Payroll Number]=b.[Payroll Number]


    GROUP BY     a.ActionDate ,
             a.Date ,
             a.[Payroll Number]
```